# Defining a shadow DOM template in javascript

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I'm creating an element with shadow dom, eventually for use in a custom element. My HTML file is already a bit bloated, so I'd ideally like to move all of my templating into the java script, rather than referencing templates in the body of my html.

I tried this approach for doing so:

```
var template = document.createElement('template'),
   div = document.createElement('div');

div.textContent = 'foo';
template.appendChild(div);

var shadow = document.body.appendChild('div').createShadowRoot();

shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode());
```

However, this throws a NotFoundError. Digging deeper, it looks like the template.content is just defined as `#documentFragment`, which seems like it could be the problem, but I don't know enough about shadow dom or templates to say for sure.

Is there a bug in my code or a better way of creating templates in javascript?

[Here is my test fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mc8s36z3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this call is invalid:

```
document.body.appendChild('div')
```

You need a regular element in the DOM, in order to mount the shadow DOM:

```
var mountingPoint = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(mountingPoint);
```

A `<template>` is an element that contains a document fragment named `content`:

> This interface is also of great use with Web components: <template> elements contains a DocumentFragment in their HTMLTemplateElement.content property. ([Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment))

So, you could replace `template.appendChild(div);` with:

```
template.content.appendChild(div);
```

Also note that with Chrome, the first parameter `deep` of the method `cloneNode` must be `true` because [default is false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode#Browser_compatibility).

```
template.content.cloneNode(true);
```

But you don't need a `<template>` element. Use the created DIV directly:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'foo';

var mountingPoint = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(mountingPoint);

var shadow = mountingPoint.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadow.appendChild(div);
```